# Linear regression - trend line with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, statistics

I am trying to display a trend line with pgfplots. I followed the instruction in the manual and looked around. I though I had implemented it correctly, but there is no regression line, and although the dots display correctly.

Any suggestions?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
   /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={}]
\addplot [color=blue, only marks] coordinates{
(   1985    ,   293.4445874757  )
(   1986    ,   279.3118605376  )
(   1987    ,   282.6149240816  )
(   1988    ,   275.0321316854  )
(   1989    ,   282.514265914   )
(   1990    ,   265.2009422222  )
(   1991    ,   275.1986687778  )
(   1992    ,   284.7559793069  )
(   1993    ,   276.545687619   )
(   1994    ,   292.6098138043  )
(   1995    ,   302.9776170115  )
(   1996    ,   319.0738164198  )
(   1997    ,   299.9292631959  )
(   1998    ,   361.3646108235  )
(   1999    ,   293.1112261224  )
(   2000    ,   294.2231206931  )
(   2001    ,   283.6616129293  )
(   2002    ,   313.2993810185  )
(   2003    ,   273.69578875    )
(   2004    ,   278.5970550926  )
(   2005    ,   286.7000069643  )
(   2006    ,   262.0665872115  )
(   2007    ,   245.7247934066  )
(   2008    ,   258.789477  )
(   2009    ,   239.1641025714  )
(   2010    ,   243.2148177778  )
(   2011    ,   240.0082707477  )
(   2012    ,   242.0303828571  )
(   2013    ,   230.697315  )};
\addplot table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]{
(   1985    ,   293.4445874757  )
(   1986    ,   279.3118605376  )
(   1987    ,   282.6149240816  )
(   1988    ,   275.0321316854  )
(   1989    ,   282.514265914   )
(   1990    ,   265.2009422222  )
(   1991    ,   275.1986687778  )
(   1992    ,   284.7559793069  )
(   1993    ,   276.545687619   )
(   1994    ,   292.6098138043  )
(   1995    ,   302.9776170115  )
(   1996    ,   319.0738164198  )
(   1997    ,   299.9292631959  )
(   1998    ,   361.3646108235  )
(   1999    ,   293.1112261224  )
(   2000    ,   294.2231206931  )
(   2001    ,   283.6616129293  )
(   2002    ,   313.2993810185  )
(   2003    ,   273.69578875    )
(   2004    ,   278.5970550926  )
(   2005    ,   286.7000069643  )
(   2006    ,   262.0665872115  )
(   2007    ,   245.7247934066  )
(   2008    ,   258.789477  )
(   2009    ,   239.1641025714  )
(   2010    ,   243.2148177778  )
(   2011    ,   240.0082707477  )
(   2012    ,   242.0303828571  )
(   2013    ,   230.697315  )};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: you need the `pgfplotstable` package to do this. for me it only works with coordinates like this  
`X Y \1  0.43\\ `

and so on

Comment: Thanks, I added the package. Strange thing now. It keeps compiling, without error, but never stops...

Comment: I am using beamer, I hope that doesn't complicate matters

Comment: works fine for me even with `beamer`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First it looks like you need to include the `pgfplotstable` package.F
I had sort of the same problem a few days ago. Writing my data like this solved it for me.:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,
        compat=1.3,
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Glukosekonzentration [\si{\gram\per\liter}]},
    ylabel={Absorption $[-]$},
    legend cell align=left,
    legend pos=north west]
    \addplot[only marks] table[row sep=\\]{
        X Y\\
        0.1 0.147\\
        0.1 0.165\\
        0.8 0.918\\
        0.8 1.149\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Messpunkte}
    \addplot table[row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] % compute a linear regression from the
    %input table
    {
        X Y\\
        0.1 0.147\\
        0.1 0.165\\
        0.8 0.918\\
        0.8 1.149\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{%
        $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
        \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$ lin. Regression} %
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

In this example you tell `pgfplots` the points belonging to the Y axes so it is able to calculate it.

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Check out `leastsquares` function from the `Asymptote` `stats` module.
`tr.asy`:

```
import graph;
import markers;
import stats;
real[] xp={
 1985
,1986
,1987
,1988
,1989
,1990
,1991
,1992
,1993
,1994
,1995
,1996
,1997
,1998
,1999
,2000
,2001
,2002
,2003
,2004
,2005
,2006
,2007
,2008
,2009
,2010
,2011
,2012
,2013
};
real[] yp={
 293.4445874757
,279.3118605376
,282.6149240816
,275.0321316854
,282.514265914 
,265.2009422222
,275.1986687778
,284.7559793069
,276.545687619 
,292.6098138043
,302.9776170115
,319.0738164198
,299.9292631959
,361.3646108235
,293.1112261224
,294.2231206931
,283.6616129293
,313.2993810185
,273.69578875  
,278.5970550926
,286.7000069643
,262.0665872115
,245.7247934066
,258.789477  
,239.1641025714
,243.2148177778
,240.0082707477
,242.0303828571
,230.697315  
};

real w=300; real h=200;
size(w,h,IgnoreAspect);

real xmin=1984; real xmax=2014;
real ymin=50; real ymax=400;
fixedscaling((xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax));

frame mark=newframe;
pen markPen=darkblue+0.8pt;
real markScale=2.2;
filldraw(mark,scale(markScale)*polygon(5),yellow,markPen);

linefit lf=leastsquares(xp,yp);
//  struct linefit {
//    real m,b;     // slope, intercept
//    real dm,db;   // standard error in slope, intercept
//    real r;       // correlation coefficient
//    real fit(real x) {
//      return m*x+b;
//    }
//  }
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
string trendStr="$y="+format("%4.2f",lf.m)+"x+"+format("%4.2f",lf.b)+"$";

draw(graph(xp,yp),nullpen, legend="data", marker(mark));

pen trendPen=red+1.3pt+opacity(0.7);
guide trendLine=graph(lf.fit,xmin+1,xmax-1);

draw(trendLine,legend=trendStr,trendPen);

add(legend(),point(S),-20S,UnFill);

xaxis(YEquals(ymin),xmin,xmax,RightTicks(Step=5,step=1));
yaxis(XEquals(xmin),ymin,ymax,LeftTicks(Step=50,step=25,beginlabel=false));
```

Run `asy -f pdf tr.asy` to get a standalone `tr.pdf`.

Comment: +1, that's really useful! In general, I think it would be useful if Asymptote solutions were presented embedded in LaTeX documents, using the document font, since I think that's one of the great things about Asymptote and also what makes it relevant for the site (otherwise one could also post a pure R solution, for instance).

Comment: @Jake: Thanks. I see a big misunderstanding here. Pure `R` or, say, `gnuplot` solutions are fundamentally different in this case. Should we also suggest to post `METAPOST` solutions 
embedded in LaTeX documents too? Because the `Asymptote` is an extension
of the `METAPOST` in exactly the same way as `LuaTeX` is to `TeX`, and it is part of the `TeXLive` distribution, which I believe `R` is not.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to step on your toes. I don't understand how standalone `Asymptote` solutions are fundamentally different from `R` or `gnuplot`, though: Taken by themselves, they allow you to generate a PDF of a visualization that can then be included in LaTeX. `gnuplot` is also included in `TeXLive`. Should we give standalone `gnuplot` answers for that reason? Maybe I'm missing something, but `Asymptote` is "only" related to TeX in the way that it can use TeX to typeset labels, right?

Comment: @Jake These are not my toes anyway :) and perhaps I'm not the right person to talk about it. I'm just trying to study the beautiful world of `TeX` & friends. The `Asymptote` is (almost) useless without working `TeX` system, it not only can, it was designed to use `TeX/LaTeX/XeLaTeX` to typeset labels,
plus it uses the same algorithm to build cubic Bezier splines,
as is used in `METAFONT/METAPOST`, and it extends it to `3D`
and to cubic Bezier surfaces; it uses `PSTricks` `pstextpath` macro to fit labels along a path, etc, etc.

Comment: Ah, okay, it is much more intertwined with TeX than I thought, then. Also, I was wrong about `gnuplot` being in TeXLive; it is on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplot), though. Sorry for the confusion.