# Differential Equation direction plot with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, asymptote

In earlier thread Jake provided some code whom successfully draws the following differential equations in the range [0; 1]

```
dy/dx=2*x
dy/dx=x*sqrt(x)
```

See: [How to draw slope fields with all the possible solution curves in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139064/how-to-draw-slope-fields-with-all-the-possible-solution-curves-in-latex/139078#139078)

I have not been able to determine how to change the range to `[-1; 1]` for both dimensions. My attempt

```
xmin=-1.1, xmax=1.1, % Axis limits
ymin=-1.1, ymax=1.1,
domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1,
```

Also, I had some trouble with the notation for a differential equation that consists of y, example `(dy/dx=x^2+y^2-1)`.

My attempt:

```
declare function={f(\x) = \x^2 + f(\x)^2 - 1;}
```

Answer (score 36):

Using PGFPlotstable, you can use a naive numerical integration scheme to find the function directly within LaTeX:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/x/.style={
        create col/expr={
            \pgfplotstablerow/201*2-1
        }
    },
    create on use/y/.style={
        create col/expr accum={
            \pgfmathaccuma+(2/201)*(abs(\pgfmathaccuma^2)+abs(\thisrow{x}^2)-1)
        }{0.6}
    }
}


\pgfplotstablenew{201}\loadedtable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90},
    domain=-1:1,
    y domain=-1:1,
    xmax=1, ymax=1,
    samples=21
]
\addplot3 [gray, quiver={u={1}, v={x^2+y^2-1}, scale arrows=0.075, every arrow/.append style={-latex}}] (x,y,0);
\addplot [thick, red] table [x=x, y=y] {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to you change the x and y values for the viewing window?

Comment: Can you explain how numerical integration is implemented with PGFPlotstable? How does it work?

Answer (score 31):

(Sets of) ordinary differential equations (ODE) can be numerically solved using `\pstODEsolve` from the `pst-ode` Plain-TeX / LaTeX package.

Integration of the ODEs is done using the Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg method (`RKF45`).

Run 2 times `lualatex` or the sequence of commands

```
latex myfile
dvips myfile
ps2pdf -dNOSAFER myfile.ps
```

on the TeX input. Either method writes the result table into a text file on the first run. The first method makes use of `luapstricks`, a PostScript interpreter recently written by Marcel Krüger.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-ode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%solve dy/dx=x^2 + y^2 - 1 numerically for different initial values of y in the
%interval x=[-1.1,1.1]; write resulting curves as tables with 100 output points
%into text files
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%y0=-0.5 --> y0=-0.5.dat
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat,algebraic,saveData]{%
  y0=-0.5%  %name of the output file `y0=-0.5.dat'
}{
  t | x[0]  %table format in `y0=-0.5.dat': x y
}{
  -1.1      %integration domain x_min=-1.1
}{
  1.1       %integration domain x_max=1.1
}{
  100       %number of output points
}{
  -0.5      %initial value y0(x_min)
}{
  t^2+x[0]^2-1  % right hand side of ODE, note the special notation:  x --> t, y --> x[0]
}

%y0=0.0 --> y0=0.0.dat
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat,algebraic,saveData]{y0=0.0}{t | x[0]}{-1.1}{1.1}{100}{0.0}{t^2+x[0]^2-1}

%y0=0.5 --> y0=0.5.dat
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat,algebraic,saveData]{y0=0.5}{t | x[0]}{-1.1}{1.1}{100}{0.5}{t^2+x[0]^2-1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\IfFileExists{y0=-0.5.dat}{}{dummy text\end{document}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis equal image, % Unit vectors for both axes have the same length
    xmin=-1.1, xmax=1.1, % Axis limits
    ymin=-1.1, ymax=1.1,
    xtick={-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1}, ytick={-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1}, % Tick marks
    no markers,
    title={$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=x^2+y^2-1$},
    view={0}{90},samples=21,domain=-1.1:1.1, y domain=-1.1:1.1, %for direction field
  ]
  \addplot3 [gray, quiver={u={1}, v={x^2+y^2-1}, scale arrows=0.075, every arrow/.append style={-latex}}] (x,y,0);
  \addplot table {y0=-0.5.dat};
  \addplot table {y0=0.0.dat};
  \addplot table {y0=0.5.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See my edit for running everything from within one file. Then you do not need the `\if...` structures

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks a lot. I assimilated your suggestion in the second code block.

Comment: I don't get the three lines, I get the arrows to show, but not the lines.  I get an error about not being able to read the tables.

Comment: @MaoYiyi: (1) Copy contents of 2nd code block into a file, say `myfile.tex`. (2) Run `pdflatex --shell-escape myfile`. (3) Open `myfile.pdf` in a PDF reader of your choice. Option `--shell-escape` is crucial here, as it allows for automatically executing the `tex,dvips,ps2pdf` chain for producing the data tables in the files `y0=*.dat`.

Answer (score 29):

[image]

`MWE` with `Asymptote`

```
% odeslope.tex:
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{asy}
import graph;
import slopefield;
import fontsize;
defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
size(200);
real dy(real x,real y) {return x^2+y^2-1;}
real xmin=-1, xmax=1;
real ymin=-0.2, ymax=1;

add(slopefield(dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax),20,deepgreen+0.4bp,Arrow));

pair C=(0.5,0.4);
draw(curve(C,dy,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax)),deepblue+1bp);

label("$C$",C,NE,UnFill);
dot(C,UnFill);

xaxis(YEquals(ymin),xmin,xmax,LeftTicks());
xaxis(YEquals(ymax),xmin,xmax);
yaxis(XEquals(xmin),ymin,ymax,RightTicks());
yaxis(XEquals(xmax),ymin,ymax);
\end{asy}
\caption{$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=x^2+y^2-1$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
%
% Process:
%
% pdflatex odeslope.tex
% asy odeslope-*.asy
% pdflatex odeslope.tex
```

Comment: Does it use first order Euler method for integration?

Comment: @AlexG: The documentation is humble about it, but the code in `slopefield.asy` looks more like `the Runge–Kutta method`.

Comment: Yes and it seems to apply some automatic step size adaption. Thus, it is quite accurate.

Comment: You only provide code and the code isn't TikZ. Can you provide some motivation and/or answer as to why this is relevant?

Comment: @Marc van Dongen: Please, not again. It was once concluded
after long and painful discussion that `TikZ/PSTriks/Metapost/Asymptote` are somewhat equivalent and the community can only benefit from answers that provide alternative approaches
to get the desired high quality graphics with `TeX` and friends.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: There was a bit of discussion about the relevance of Asymptote in the comments to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117436/2552, and the votes and lack of opposition on http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3518/2552 also seem to be quite a clear indicator that Asymptote  can be considered equivalent to TikZ/PSTricks for the purposes of this site. I think the community has kind of come to the conclusion that questions about generating graphics can be answered with different tools (even if the question asks about a particular one) without having to list the pros and cons of the ...

Comment: ... (continued) chosen package. Almost every TikZ answer has a PSTricks answer simply starting with "With PSTricks, just for fun" or "Run with XeLaTeX", and vice versa.

Comment: @Jake: Not that Asymptote is off-site, but the OP clearly asks for a `pgfplots` solution.

Comment: @AlexG: I know, but as I said, many questions get answers using different tools, even if the question asks for a particular one. The community has more or less agreed on this being a welcome thing (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/downvoting-answers-exploiting-different-approaches-with-respect-to-the-initial-q): Even if the answers might not be relevant to the asker because they're bound to a particular tool, other people will definitely benefit from seeing a range of different approaches.

Comment: @Jake: Ok, agreed and thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: @Marc van Dongen: new members don't have to be aware of the history, they just need an unbiased view of possible alternatives they can use. Also, this question is kind of an extension of the earlier thread, where the OP was `looking for a simple method` to `use repetitively on different equations; without having to code each equation; to make/produce/draw the slope field of that equation`.

Comment: @g.kov How can we change the size of the arrows in you code?

Comment: @BlackMild Assume that you don't know yet, it is [tickfactor](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/blob/master/base/slopefield.asy#L6).

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998 I checked, it is tickfactor! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 17):

A PSTricks solution, it can be run with `xelatex` but that takes a lot of time in difference to `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-ode}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=3}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.1,1.1)
\psaxes[ticksize=0 4pt,axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=inner,subticks=20,
        Ox=-1,Oy=-1](-1,-1)(1,1)
\psset{arrows=->,algebraic}
\psVectorfield[linecolor=black!60](-0.9,-0.9)(0.9,0.9){ x^2+y^2-1 }
%y0_a=-0.5
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_a}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{-0.5}{t^2+x[0]^2-1}
%y0_b=0.0
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_b}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{0.0}{t^2+x[0]^2-1}
%y0_c=0.5
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_c}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{0.5}{t^2+x[0]^2-1}

\psset{arrows=-,linewidth=1pt}%
\listplot[linecolor=red  ]{y0_a}
\listplot[linecolor=green]{y0_b}
\listplot[linecolor=blue ]{y0_c}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]