# Asymptote slopefield

Tags: asymptote

The optional arrows in `slopefield.asy` do not work correctly for dy/dx=-x/y. I can't think of a generic (elegant) way to make them work using its current methodology. Here is an mwe adapted from [k.gov](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139114/differential-equation-direction-plot-with-pgfplots/139137#139137):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{asy}
import graph;
import slopefield;
size(200);
// Global variables
real eps=0.0001;
real large=1/eps;
//
// Callable function dy/dx=f(x,y)
//
real dy(real x, real y) {
real slope;
// Guard for divide by zero
if (fabs(y) > eps) {
 slope = -(x/y+1.0);}
else { 
 slope = -sgn(x)*large;} //Problem specific cludge
return slope;
};
//
real xmin=-1, xmax=1;
real ymin=-1, ymax=1;
pair pmin=(xmin,ymin);
pair pmax=(xmax,ymax);
add(slopefield(dy,pmin,pmax,20,deepgreen+0.4bp,Arrow));
xaxis(YEquals(ymin),xmin,xmax,LeftTicks());
xaxis(YEquals(ymax),xmin,xmax);
yaxis(XEquals(xmin),ymin,ymax,RightTicks());
yaxis(XEquals(xmax),ymin,ymax);
\end{asy}
\caption{$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-(\frac{x}{y}+1)$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I have two potential solutions for you.

The first adds a new version of the `slopefield` function that works for slopefields specified as `(dx/dt, dy/dt)` rather than `dy/dx`.

```
import slopefield;

picture slopefield(pair dir(real,real), pair a, pair b,
                   int nx=nmesh, int ny=nx,
                   real tickfactor=0.5, pen p=currentpen, arrowbar arrow=None)
{
  picture pic;
  real dx=(b.x-a.x)/nx;
  real dy=(b.y-a.y)/ny;
  real step=0.5*tickfactor*min(dx,dy);

  for(int i=0; i <= nx; ++i) {
    real x=a.x+i*dx;
    for(int j=0; j <= ny; ++j) {
      pair cp=(x,a.y+j*dy);
      pair direction=unit(dir(cp.x,cp.y));
      draw(pic,(cp-step*direction)--(cp+step*direction),p,arrow); 
    }
  }
  clip(pic,box(a,b));
  return pic;
}
```

Here's the code in context, and the result. (Note that I've used the `asypictureB` package because it gives better debug output, but the `asymptote` package would still work.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{asyheader}
import slopefield;
picture slopefield(pair dir(real,real), pair a, pair b,
                   int nx=nmesh, int ny=nx,
                   real tickfactor=0.5, pen p=currentpen, arrowbar arrow=None)
{
  picture pic;
  real dx=(b.x-a.x)/nx;
  real dy=(b.y-a.y)/ny;
  real step=0.5*tickfactor*min(dx,dy);

  for(int i=0; i <= nx; ++i) {
    real x=a.x+i*dx;
    for(int j=0; j <= ny; ++j) {
      pair cp=(x,a.y+j*dy);
      pair direction=unit(dir(cp.x,cp.y));
      draw(pic,(cp-step*direction)--(cp+step*direction),p,arrow); 
    }
  }
  clip(pic,box(a,b));
  return pic;
}
\end{asyheader}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{asypicture}{}
settings.outformat = "pdf";
import graph;
size(200);

//
// Callable function (dx/dt, dy/dt)=f(x,y)
//
pair direction(real x, real y) {
  return (y, -(x + y));
}

//
real xmin=-1, xmax=1;
real ymin=-1, ymax=1;
pair pmin=(xmin,ymin);
pair pmax=(xmax,ymax);
add(slopefield(direction,pmin,pmax,20,deepgreen+0.4bp,Arrow));
xaxis(YEquals(ymin),xmin,xmax,LeftTicks());
xaxis(YEquals(ymax),xmin,xmax);
yaxis(XEquals(xmin),ymin,ymax,RightTicks());
yaxis(XEquals(xmax),ymin,ymax);
\end{asypicture}
\caption{$\left(\frac{dx}{dt}, \frac{dy}{dt}\right)=(y, -(x+y))$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The result is very nice, but it also allows right-to-left arrows. This is much more natural for the graph in question, but I was also interested to see if I could do something that was aimed at the `dy/dx =` case.  Here's what I came up with:
[image]

The idea is the following.

- First, a "quiet divide" function is added that, when division by zero is attempted, returns a non-finite value rather than throwing an error. The function is rewritten to use this `quietdivide` function rather than `/`.
- Second, the relevant `slopefield` function is rewritten (with helper functions) to take the following actions if it encounters a non-finite `dy/dx` value:

  1. Attempt to compute the "limiting direction" by averaging the directions at 
     a number of randomly chosen points near the problematic point. If the chosen 
     points all give similar directions, this is considered to have succeeded.
  2. Try the same thing again, but in such a way that the positive and negative 
     vertical directions have no distance between them. If this succeeds, draw a 
     line in the specified direction, but with no directional arrow.
  3. If neither of the two preceding limit approximations succeeds, just draw a
     directionless point.

The code:

```
import graph;
import slopefield;
import stats;
size(200);

real quietdivide(real s, real t) { return (abs(t) >= 1e-6) ? s / t : inf; }

real epsilon = 1e-3;
real maxstdev = 5e-2;

private real limitdirection_helper(pair[] datapoints) {
  real[] xdata, ydata;
  for (pair datapoint : datapoints) {
    xdata.push(datapoint.x);
    ydata.push(datapoint.y);
  }
  real xstdev = stdev(xdata), ystdev = stdev(ydata);
  real[] toreturn;
  if (xstdev < maxstdev && ystdev < maxstdev) {
    pair limitdirection = (mean(xdata), mean(ydata));
    return angle(limitdirection);
  } else {
    return inf;
  }
}

// If returnedarray[0] exists and is finite, then it specifies the (approximate) limit direction in radians.
// If returnedarray[1] exists and is finite, then it specifies the limit direction mod reflection in radians on the interval (-pi/2, pi/2]. This is useful primarily because it is defined when the limit slope is vertical but the limit direction (up vs down) is not defined.
// If neither of the two preceeding conditions holds, then no limit was found.
real[] limitdirection(pair f(real x, real y), real x, real y) {
  pair[] datapoints;
  int maxiter = 100, numdatapoints = 20;
  for (int i = 0; i < maxiter && datapoints.length < numdatapoints; ++i) {
    pair delta = epsilon * Gaussrandpair();
    pair possibledirection = f(x + delta.x, y + delta.y);
    if (finite(possibledirection)) datapoints.push(unit(possibledirection));
  }
  if (datapoints.length < numdatapoints) return new real[0];  // could not find enough nearby finite points to compute limit
  real[] toreturn;
  toreturn.push(limitdirection_helper(datapoints));
  pair[] datapointsmod2 = map(new pair(pair datapoint) {
      real angle = angle(datapoint);
      return expi(2*angle);
    }, datapoints);
  toreturn.push(limitdirection_helper(datapointsmod2) / 2);
  return toreturn;
}

picture slopefield(real f(real,real), pair a, pair b,
                   int nx=nmesh, int ny=nx,
                   real tickfactor=0.5, pen p=currentpen, arrowbar arrow=None)
{
  picture pic;
  real dx=(b.x-a.x)/nx;
  real dy=(b.y-a.y)/ny;
  real step=0.5*tickfactor*min(dx,dy);

  for(int i=0; i <= nx; ++i) {
    real x=a.x+i*dx;
    for(int j=0; j <= ny; ++j) {
      pair cp=(x,a.y+j*dy);
      real slope=f(cp.x,cp.y);
      if (finite(slope)) {
        real mp=step/sqrt(1+slope^2);
        draw(pic,(cp.x-mp,cp.y-mp*slope)--(cp.x+mp,cp.y+mp*slope),p,arrow);
      } else {
    real[] limitdirection = limitdirection(new pair(real x, real y) {
        return (1, f(x,y));
      }, cp.x, cp.y);
    if (alias(limitdirection, null)
        || limitdirection.length == 0
        || (limitdirection.length == 1 && !finite(limitdirection[0]))
        || (!finite(limitdirection[0]) && !finite(limitdirection[1]))) {
      draw(pic, cp, p);  // just a small dot
    } else if (finite(limitdirection[0])) {
      pair direction = expi(limitdirection[0]);
          draw(pic,(cp-step*direction)--(cp+step*direction),p,arrow);
    } else {  // finite(limitdirection[1])
      pair direction = expi(limitdirection[1]);
          draw(pic,(cp-step*direction)--(cp+step*direction),p);  // line with no arrow
    }
      }
    }
  }
  clip(pic,box(a,b));
  return pic;
}

// Callable function dy/dx=f(x,y)
real dy(real x, real y) {  return -(quietdivide(x,y) + 1); }
//
real xmin=-1, xmax=1;
real ymin=-1, ymax=1;
pair pmin=(xmin,ymin);
pair pmax=(xmax,ymax);
add(slopefield(dy,pmin,pmax,20,deepgreen+0.4bp,Arrow));
xaxis(YEquals(ymin),xmin,xmax,LeftTicks());
xaxis(YEquals(ymax),xmin,xmax);
yaxis(XEquals(xmin),ymin,ymax,RightTicks());
yaxis(XEquals(xmax),ymin,ymax);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thx!

Comment: @Charles Staats Is Asymptote is real 3D and TikZ is fake 3D? I saw comment of Black Mild at [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302814/asymptote-slopefield/303422#303422)?

Answer (score 6):

I have added some changes to `curve()` to make it compatible with your first suggestion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{asyheader}
import slopefield;
picture slopefield(pair dir(real,real), pair a, pair b,
                   int nx=nmesh, int ny=nx,
                   real tickfactor=0.5, pen p=currentpen, arrowbar arrow=Arrow)
{
  picture pic;
  real dx=(b.x-a.x)/nx;
  real dy=(b.y-a.y)/ny;
  real step=0.5*tickfactor*min(dx,dy);

  for(int i=0; i <= nx; ++i) {
    real x=a.x+i*dx;
    for(int j=0; j <= ny; ++j) {
      pair cp=(x,a.y+j*dy);
      pair direction=unit(dir(cp.x,cp.y));
      draw(pic,(cp-step*direction)--(cp+step*direction),p,arrow); 
    }
  }
  clip(pic,box(a,b));
  return pic;
}
path curve(pair c, pair f(real,real), pair a, pair b, int maxsteps) 
{
  real step=stepfraction*(b.x-a.x);     
  real halfstep=0.5*step;
  real sixthstep=step/6;

//  path follow(real sign) {
    pair cp=c;
    guide g=cp;
    real dx,dy;
    real factor=1;
    int i=0;
    do {
      ++i;
      pair slope;
      pair S(pair z) {
        slope=unit(f(z.x,z.y));
        return factor*slope; // sign/sqrt(1+slope^2)*(1,slope);
      }
      pair S3;
      pair advance() {
        pair S0=S(cp);
        pair S1=S(cp+halfstep*S0);
        pair S2=S(cp+halfstep*S1);
        S3=S(cp+step*S2);
        pair cp0=cp+sixthstep*(S0+2S1+2S2+S3);
        dx=min(cp0.x-a.x,b.x-cp0.x);
        dy=min(cp0.y-a.y,b.y-cp0.y);
        return cp0;
      }
      pair cp0=advance();
      if(dx < 0) {
        factor=(step+dx)/step;
        cp0=advance();
        g=g..{S3}cp0{S3};
        break;
      }
      if(dy < 0) {
        factor=(step+dy)/step;
        cp0=advance();
        g=g..{S3}cp0{S3};
        break;
      }
      cp=cp0;
      g=g..{S3}cp{S3};
    } while (i <=maxsteps && dx > 0 && dy > 0);
    return g;
//  }

//  return reverse(follow(-1))&follow(1);
}

//path curve(pair c, real f(real), pair a, pair b)
//{
//  return curve(c,new real(real x, real y){return f(x);},a,b);
//}

\end{asyheader}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{asypicture}{}
import graph;
import slopefield;
size(300);
// Global variables
real eps=0.0001;
real large=1/eps;
//
// Callable function dy/dx=f(x,y)
//
pair direction(real x, real y) {
  return (y, -(x + y));
}
//
int max=16;
real xmin=-2, xmax=2;
real ymin=-2, ymax=2;
pair pmin=(xmin,ymin);
pair pmax=(xmax,ymax);
add(slopefield(direction,pmin,pmax,20,deepgreen+0.4bp));

pair C1=(0.9,0.9);
draw(curve(C1,direction,pmin,pmax,max),deepblue+1bp);
pair C2=(-1.2,0.0);
draw(curve(C2,direction,pmin,pmax,max),deepred+1bp);

label("$i.c.$",C1,NE,UnFill);
dot(C1,UnFill);

xaxis(YEquals(ymin),xmin,xmax,LeftTicks());
xaxis(YEquals(ymax),xmin,xmax);
yaxis(XEquals(xmin),ymin,ymax,RightTicks());
yaxis(XEquals(xmax),ymin,ymax);
\end{asypicture}
\caption{$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-(\frac{x}{y}+1)$}
\end{figure}
% % %
\end{document}
```

The `int maxsteps` is needed because `dx` and `dy` stay negative. Bi-directional `follow()` isn't needed. I haven't time to make this elegant. Log decreasing steps would perhaps tidy up the part of the curve at the origin. Time prevents me from doing more ...

[image]