# Phase Plane Plot using pst-ode

Tags: pgfplots, pstricks, pst-plot

I am trying to incorporate the solution to the nonlinear differential equations

> x' = x + y + x^2 + y^2
>
> y' = x - y - x^2 + y^2

The solution to these nonlinear differential equations were found with a saddle point at (0,0) and an equilibrium point at (-1, -1).  The equation was solved using Matlab and produced this result:

[image]

I have been trying to plot some of the lines and simplified the plot to produce these points with

> x0=[-2.5,-1.5,-1, -0.5]; and
>
> y0=-2.5.

This is the result:

[image]

I am trying to elegantly plot this and came across `pst-ode`.  I attempted to get a plot to match but so far have failed miserably!  I followed the code given here: [Differential Equation direction plot with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139114/differential-equation-direction-plot-with-pgfplots/139140#139140) but still no luck.  Can you help me get the correct plot to match the original plot showing the lines.

I'm uncertain how to incorporate the second differential equation to come up with the correct plot.  Thanks for your help!

Here is my attempt this far:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-ode}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=3}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.1,1.1)
\psaxes[ticksize=0 4pt,axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=inner,subticks=20,
        Ox=-2.5,Oy=-2.5](-1,-1)(1,1)
\psset{arrows=->,algebraic}
\psVectorfield[linecolor=black!60](-0.9,-0.9)(0.9,0.9){ x + y + x^2 + y^2 }
%y0_a=-2.5
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_a}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{-2.5}{t + x[0] + t^2 + x[0]^2}
%y0_b=-1.5
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_b}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{-1.5}{t + x[0] + t^2 + x[0]^2}
%y0_c=-1
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_c}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{-1}{t + x[0] + t^2 + x[0]^2}
%y0_c=-0.5
\pstODEsolve[algebraicOutputFormat]{y0_d}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{-0.5}{t + x[0] + t^2 + x[0]^2}


\psset{arrows=-,linewidth=1pt}%
\listplot[linecolor=red  ]{y0_a}
\listplot[linecolor=green]{y0_b}
\listplot[linecolor=blue ]{y0_c}
\listplot[linecolor=blue ]{y0_d}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean you tried `quiver` from pgfplots? Can you show us a/the failing code?

Comment: I did not try `quiver`.  I made my first attempt here with `pst-ode`.  Am I going down the wrong path?

Comment: Probably the right path. PS can do more computations than PGF. But I am not familiar with the magical PStricks family.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The right-hand side of the given system of ODEs

> dx/dt = x + y + x^2 + y^2
>
> dy/dt = x − y − x^2 + y^2

translates into `algebraic` notation, used by **`\pstODEsolve`** as its last argument, as

```
\def\odeRHS{
  x[0] + x[1] + x[0]^2 + x[1]^2
|
  x[0] − x[1] − x[0]^2 + x[1]^2
}
```

Here, in the given case, the RHS does *not* depend on *t*, the independent integration parameter.

We solve the set of ODEs many times with varying initial conditions, that is, starting points *x0* and *y0* in the *x*-*y* plane. Those starting points are aligned on a 0.1 by 0.1 raster which is shifted by 0.05 in *x* and *y* to avoid the saddle point as starting point. (This would not do any harm, but produce a coloured dot at (0,0).) The starting points are specified in algebraic notation as the last-but-one argument of `\pstODEsolve`.

[image]
The code is quite demanding in terms of TeX memory due to the nested loops. The TeX memory [↗**can be enlarged**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7954) for the `latex` engine, but it may be easier to just use `dvilualatex` instead:

> ```
> dvilualatex phasePlane
> dvips phasePlane
> ps2pdf phasePlane.ps
> ```

Direct PDF output with `lualatex` is possible nowadays, thanks to Marcel Krüger's [PostScript interpreter](https://ctan.org/pkg/luapstricks) written in Lua. (It is just a bit slower than `ps2pdf`):

> ```
> lualatex phasePlane
> ```

**The code:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-ode,multido}

%right hand side in algebraic notation
\def\odeRHS{
  x[0] + x[1] + x[0]^2 + x[1]^2
|
  x[0] - x[1] - x[0]^2 + x[1]^2
}

\def\tEnd{10} % end of integration interval; in- or de-crease to have longer/shorter lines
\def\outputSteps{500} %increase for smoother lines (and larger PDF file)

\definecolor[ps]{random}{rgb}{Rand Rand Rand} %define random colour

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=3}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.95,-2.8)(1.6,1.6)
  \psaxes[ticksize=0 4pt,axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=inner,
    dx=0.5,dy=0.5,Dx=0.5,Dy=0.5,Ox=-2.5,Oy=-2.5,subticks=5
  ](-2.5,-2.5)(1.5,1.5)

  \rput(-0.5,-2.75){$x$}
  \rput(-2.9,-0.5){$y$}

  \psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none](-2.5,-2.5)(1.5,1.5)}%

  % Solve ODE for initial conditions (starting points) on a 0.1 by 0.1 raster
  \multido{\ii=0+1,\rx=-2.55+0.1}{42}{
    \multido{\ij=0+1,\ry=-2.55+0.1}{42}{
      \pstODEsolve[algebraicAll]{line_\ii_\ij}{x[0] | x[1]}{0}{\tEnd}{\outputSteps}{\rx | \ry}{\odeRHS}
    } 
  }
  %plot the lines previously computed
  \multido{\ii=0+1}{42}{
    \multido{\ij=0+1}{42}{
      \listplot[linecolor=random]{line_\ii_\ij}
    }  
  }

  \endpsclip
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  Sincerely appreciated.  How to go about getting the saddle point at (0,0) also?  Thanks again!

Comment: I may need to revise the `pst-ode` code in order catch the numerical underflow error, preventing the code from chrashing but just stopping the integration instead.

Comment: Is there a way to add to this plot values after the saddle point.  In Matlab, a STOP had to be placed close to the "infinite" solution then step the simulation by 3 to continue plotting.  Can this same principle be coded here?  Thanks!

Comment: Of course, you can manually add lines with starting points (initial conditions) for `x[0]` and `x[1]` around the saddle point. For example `{0 | 0.1}` and integrate in two directions (two calls of `\pstODEsolve` with *t*=[0,-1] first and then with *t*=[0,1]).

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to do a sweep like you did for points below the saddle point `% Starting point above saddle (x=0, y=0.1) and integrate over t=[0,2.5] and t=[0,-2.5]
\multido{\i=0+1,\rx=0.1+0.1}{9}{
  \pstODEsolve[algebraicAll]{aboveSaddleR_\i}{x[0] | x[1]}{0}{2.5}{1000}{\rx | 0.1}{\odeRHS}
  }
  \multido{\i=0+1,\rx=0.1+0.1}{9}{
  \pstODEsolve[...
  }`  and then plot `%line above saddle
  \multido{\i=0+1}{9}{
  \listplot[linecolor=blue]{aboveSaddleR_\i}
  }`.Did not get that to work.  Can we sweep this 'above saddle' points?  Thanks~

Comment: Ok, pst-ode has been updated (v0.8, [2017/06/12]). This should answer most of your questions.

Comment: Sincerest Thanks for providing this elegant solution!

Comment: I was looking for a way to randomly set the line colours. Now we get a result which is close to the Matlab output. I updated `pst-ode` once more (v 0.9), but the code should happily compile with v 0.8. Occasionally, the alogrithm entered an infinite loop. Thanks for the interesting topic which helped me to improve the pkg.

Comment: Instead of `\ifdefined\outputmode\outputmode=0\fi` you can run `lualatex --output-format=dvi <file>`

Comment: Yes, I know, but for the unaware user (using editors with pre-configured tool invocation) it seems safer to me like so.

Comment: that is true ...

Comment: BTW, @Herbert, thanks for the random colour suggestion on the `pstricks` mailing-list.

Comment: also interesting: `\definecolor[ps]{random}{cmyk}{0.2 0.2 0.2 Rand}`

Comment: @AlexG Do you have measured how much slower this is with LuaLaTeX? It seems like an interesting computational benchmark.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks a lot you for feedback! The difference is noticeable, though I did not do a rigorous measurement. I am having another problem when running with `lualatex` which puzzles me more. Could we discuss this in a chatroom?

Comment: @AlexG Sure, I created a room.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Ok, I did the benchmark test: `lualatex`: `user    19m11.348s` ; `dvilualatex+dvips+ps2pdf`: `user    1m5.074s` .