# Pgfplots of flow lines of an ode systems

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to have a tikz diagram of the flow lines of this onion shaped flow:

x'(t)=-16y

y'(t)=(x^2 + y^2 + 4y + 3)(x^2 + y^2 - 4y + 3)

in the square -4 < x < 4, -4 < y < 4. These flow lines may also be made as level sets of

g(x,y) = x(x^2 + y^2 - 9)/(x^2 + y^2 - 1)

Unfortunately I am totally unskilled in pgfplots... so I came here for some help like a poor beggar!

(The following quick picture by Maple was not satisfactory, because lines are too thick, because I don't want to see the axes nor numbers, because I'd like to have them gracefully spaced, and because the arrowheads concentrate on the equilibria making a horrible spot)

[image]

Comment: As a start I suppose you could try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18384/

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139141/121799 (and maybe also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471743/121799).

Comment: @Pietro Majer: do you mind to add tag `asymptote` ?

Comment: @BlackMild, why should he do that? If you have an Asymptote solution, just add it as an answer. Then you will see if this is fine for Pietro and/or the others.