# Rotation number of a vector field

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-calc

I am trying to define what is the rotation number of a vector field and for this I need to show the following graph (or one quite similar)

[image]

my attempt is as follows (I used as template the code given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471741/248335)): It is not very good I know that it can be improved from two aspects:

1. The field is quite improvised trying to reach something similar
2. I would also like to graph fields in the plane as `F(x,y)=(P(x,y),Q(x,y))` like [this](https://www.geogebra.org/m/VzZcSqzZ).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=\x*\y-3*tan(\x+\y);}]
\def\xmax{3} \def\xmin{-3}
\def\ymax{3} \def\ymin{-3}
\def\nx{15}  \def\ny{15}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\hx}{(\xmax-\xmin)/\nx}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hy}{(\ymax-\ymin)/\ny}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\nx}
\foreach \j in {0,...,\ny}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}
\draw[gray,-stealth,shift={({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}] (0,0)--(.1,.1*\yprime);
}

%\draw[->] (\xmin-.5,0)--(\xmax+.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
%\draw[->] (0,\ymin-.5)--(0,\ymax+.5) node[above left] {$y$};

\draw[red,line width = 1 pt]
    (-2,2) .. controls + (-1,0) and +(-0.5,0) ..
    (-1,-1) .. controls + (1,0) and + (-0.2,0) ..
    (1,-2) .. controls + (0.2,0) and + (2,0) ..
    (2,1) .. controls + (-2,0) and + (1,0) ..
    (-2,2) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: I guess the code of your MWE from this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471741/draw-solution-curves-of-a-differential-equation-with-tikz Please cite that link for the flow of info on codes that this forum aiming at, for convenience of other users.

Comment: What does the red closed curve mean?

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998 The red curve is simply a smooth closed curve that surrounds the origin, it could simply be a circle but as it is an example it is about giving any curve. I tried to do it with the Bezier curve without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to rotation numbers, it is not the size of the vectors in the field that matter, but only their directions. I therefore prefer to draw all vectors with the same length. For the arrows along the path, I suggest to have small disks in the background, since I think it makes it more clear when following the path to find the rotation number.

Below is an example done in MetaPost (which is what I have learned), but it can easily be translated into tikz/asymptote/pstricks. (The `\startMPpage` and `\stopMPpage` are only there for me to be able to run context on the file directly, and not really part of the figure.)

```
\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
s:=1.5cm ;

% This defines the vector field
vardef u(expr x,y) = (x*x*x*x-6*x*x*y*y+y*y*y*y) enddef ;
vardef v(expr x,y) = (4*x*x*x*y-4*x*y*y*y) enddef ;

% Vector plot of the vector field
% Note that the base points of the arrows are not at the foot but at the "stomach".
path tmparr ;
for x = -4 step 0.25 until 4 :
    for y = -4 step 0.25 until 4 :
        if ((x,y) = (0,0)):
        else:
            tmparr := (origin -- unitvector (u(x,y), v(x,y))) scaled 0.2s ;
            tmparr := tmparr shifted - center tmparr ;
            drawarrow  tmparr shifted ((x,y) scaled s) withcolor 0.8white;
        fi;
    endfor ;
endfor ;

% The red path
path p ; p = ((1,-2.5){up}..{dir 120}(3,2)..{dir -80}(-2,1)..(-2,-2)..cycle) scaled s ;
draw p withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor darkred ;

% The arrows along the path
numeric N ; N := 30 ;
pair tmpxy ;

for l = 1 upto N:
    tmpxy := point l/N along p ;
    tmparr := (origin -- unitvector (u(xpart tmpxy,ypart tmpxy), v(xpart tmpxy,ypart tmpxy))) scaled 0.3s ;
    tmparr := tmparr shifted - center tmparr ;
    fill (fullcircle scaled 0.3s) shifted tmpxy withcolor 0.9[darkblue,white];
    draw (fullcircle scaled 0.3s) shifted tmpxy withpen pencircle scaled 0.25 withcolor 0.3[darkblue,white] ;
    drawarrow tmparr shifted tmpxy withcolor darkblue ;
endfor ;

% Labeling the point
dotlabel.bot("$p$", origin) withpen pencircle scaled 3 ;

\stopMPpage
```

Output:

[image: Vector plot with directions along a path]

**Update**

With some modifications, here is a version that can be used on [Troy's nice MetaPost preview page](http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/) (I needed to do some small modifications, so not exactly the same):

```
s:=1.5cm ;

% This defines the vector field
vardef u(expr x,y) = (x*x*x*x-6*x*x*y*y+y*y*y*y) enddef ;
vardef v(expr x,y) = (4*x*x*x*y-4*x*y*y*y) enddef ;

% Vector plot of the vector field
% Note that the base points of the arrows are not at the foot but at the "stomach".
path tmparr ;
for x = -4 step 0.25 until 4 :
    for y = -4 step 0.25 until 4 :
        if ((x,y) = (0,0)):
        else:
            tmparr := (origin -- unitvector (u(x,y), v(x,y))) scaled 0.2s ;
            tmparr := tmparr shifted - center tmparr ;
            drawarrow  tmparr shifted ((x,y) scaled s) withcolor 0.8white;
        fi;
    endfor ;
endfor ;

% The red path
path p ; p = ((1,-2.5){up}..{dir 120}(3,2)..{dir -80}(-2,1)..(-2,-2)..cycle) scaled s ;
draw p withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor red ;

% The arrows along the path
numeric N ; N := 30 ;
numeric pL ; pL := arclength(p) ;
pair tmpxy ;


for l = 1 upto N:
    tmpxy := point (arctime (l/N)*pL of p) of p ;
    tmparr := (origin -- unitvector (u(xpart tmpxy,ypart tmpxy), v(xpart tmpxy,ypart tmpxy))) scaled 0.3s ;
    tmparr := tmparr shifted - center tmparr ;
    fill (fullcircle scaled 0.3s) shifted tmpxy withcolor 0.9[blue,white];
    draw (fullcircle scaled 0.3s) shifted tmpxy withpen pencircle scaled 0.25 withcolor 0.3[blue,white] ;
    drawarrow tmparr shifted tmpxy withcolor blue ;
endfor ;
```

Comment: Hello this was much more than I expected. I don't use that program, one question: can I use that same code to compile it online or do I have to download the program?

Comment: I updated with a version that you can run onilne. I am so used to context, so I did not think of the fact that darkred and darkblue are not standard colors in metapost. I also forgot that `point l/N along p` is not standard either (perhaps in the metafun extension). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate it a thousand times! Could you see this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/644238/248335)? I think that with your method it would also come out, I have tried it without much success since I do not know much about the program.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, and I played a bit (works fine for some flows), but for streamplots one seem to need to code a bit more to get something that looks nice. Difficult to "compete with Mathematica". You could try with [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/plot_streamplot.html) in case you like that look of it.

Comment: A little question, is it possible to orient the red curve? (for example counterclockwise)

Comment: Yes, you could for example do `draw subpath (1,2) of p withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor red ;`. Try some different values instead of 1 and 2.

Comment: I think I asked wrong, sorry. I mean to be able to put arrows that indicate the orientation (counterclockwise) in the red curve.

Comment: `drawarrow` instead of `draw` in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `TikZ` solution. Define a `pic` which is an arrow of length `\rotlen` (I set at `.5cm`) in the direction of `(1,f(x,y))`. Then using `foreach` during the drawing of each segment of the curve, place the `pic` at each `pos`.

The calculation `f(.03514*\yyy,.03514*\xxx)` is to convert points to cm.

To add arrows to the original (red) path, use the `decorations.markings` library. I defined a style `myarrow` that takes a position argument, so adding `myarrow=.8` to the `\draw` options will draw an arrow 80% along the curve. If you want to add more than one arrow, you have to add them in order. For example, `\draw[red, line width = 1 pt, myarrow=.32, myarrow=.8]` will add two arrows, one at position `.32` and one at position `.8` as shown. (Don't switch the order—it won't work.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{perp/.pic={\path(0,0); \pgfgetlastxy{\xx}{\yy}\pgfmathsetmacro{\xxx}{\xx}\pgfmathsetmacro{\yyy}{\yy}
        \draw[blue,-stealth,thick](0,0)--($(0,0)!\rotlen!(1,{f(.03514*\yyy,.03514*\xxx)})$);},
    myarrow/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}}, postaction={decorate}},
    myarrow/.default={.5}}

\def\rotlen{.5cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=\x*\y-3*tan(\x+\y);}]
\def\xmax{3} \def\xmin{-3}
\def\ymax{3} \def\ymin{-3}
\def\nx{15}  \def\ny{15}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\hx}{(\xmax-\xmin)/\nx}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hy}{(\ymax-\ymin)/\ny}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\nx}
\foreach \j in {0,...,\ny}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}
\draw[gray,-stealth,shift={({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}] (0,0)--(.1,.1*\yprime);
}

%\draw[->] (\xmin-.5,0)--(\xmax+.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
%\draw[->] (0,\ymin-.5)--(0,\ymax+.5) node[above left] {$y$};

\draw[red, line width = 1 pt, myarrow=.32, myarrow=.8]
    (-2,2) .. controls + (-1,0) and +(-0.5,0) ..
    (-1,-1)foreach \t in {0, 0.2, ..., .8} {pic [pos=\t] {perp} } .. controls + (1,0) and + (-0.2,0) ..
    (1,-2)foreach \t in {0, 0.2, ..., .8} {pic [pos=\t] {perp} } .. controls + (0.2,0) and + (2,0) ..
    (2,1)foreach \t in {0, 0.2, ..., .8} {pic [pos=\t] {perp} } .. controls + (-2,0) and + (1,0) ..
    (-2,2)foreach \t in {0, 0.2, ..., .8} {pic [pos=\t] {perp} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! Thank you very much

Comment: One question, how can I put a sense (for example counterclockwise) to the red curve?

Comment: Adding an arrow to the middle of a curve requires the `decorations.markings` library. Give me a few minutes. I'll add it to my solution. It's too long for a comment.

Comment: @Zaragosa: I updated my solution.

Comment: (+1) Thank you!