# Use solution of first order ODE in another plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following differential equation: `$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = \alpha \frac{x}{x + c}$`

And I have the function `$p(t) = \frac{x(t)}{x(t)+c}$`.
I want to plot the function *p*. How can I do that with Ti*k*Z?

Comment: What are the values for alpha and c? What is the initial condition x(t=0)?

Comment: alpha, c, and x(0) have whatever values I want.

Comment: Yes, of course. But I would like to have some values to start with.

Answer (score 2):

It is a basic of drawing. You can check [TikZ/PGF documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to see the syntax `\draw plot`. Also searching in this forum about `graph` and `plot`, etc.

Here is one way.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={c=1.2;cgap=.3;
        xmin=c-4;xleft=c-cgap;
        xmax=c+4;xright=c+cgap;
        p(\x)=\x/(\x-c);}]
\draw[->] (xmin,0)--(xmax,0) node[below right]{$x$};    
\draw[->] (0,{p(xleft)})--(0,{p(xright)}) node[below left]{$y$};
\draw[dashed] (xmin,1)--(xmax,1) 
(c,{p(xleft)})--(c,{p(xright)});
\path (0,0) node[below left]{O} (c,0) node[below right]{$c$};
\draw[thick,magenta] 
plot[domain=xmin:xleft] (\x,{p(\x)})
plot[domain=xright:xmax] (\x,{p(\x)}) node[above left=2mm]{$p(x)=\dfrac{x}{x-c}$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion but I think my question was maybe not written well enough. x is a function of t in my setting. I edited it so that it was more comprehensible.
I managed to solve my issue by solving the ODE using scipy, computing the values of p, and then using the data to plot p in my latex file. Still, I don't know if there is a solution to do all of this in a latex file

Comment: There is, with pkg `pst-ode` for example.

Comment: @avincigu I misread your interesting  question. Is there an initial condition of the differential equation?

Comment: Here is a way with TikZ https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471743/140722

Comment: Since [scipy is part of Sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/numerical_sage/scipy.html) this should be easy with the [sagetex package](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex?lang=en): just calculate and force the data through tikz. I have numerous examples of plotting data through tikz, such as the [Cantor function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241622/plotting-the-cantor-function). If you want help, just give your code for scipy, the values of your constants, and the picture of the resulting plot so I can make sure I haven't made any mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried `pst-ode` but could not make it work. I will stick to my solution using Python and scipy.

Comment: @avincigu : `pst-ode` example added.

Answer (score 2):

All within LaTeX, as requested: solving ODE and post-processing solution with `\pstODEsolve` from package `pst-ode`, plotting result with `pgfplots`.

Typeset twice with `lualatex` or `latex + dvips + ps2pdf -dNOSAFER`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-ode}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% define some constants / initial condition
\pstVerb{
  tx@Dict begin
    /alpha 1.0 def
    /const 1.0 def
    /xinit 1.0 def
  end
}

\pstODEsolve[algebraicAll,saveData]{x_p_vs_t}{ % result saved in file x_p_vs_t.dat
  t | x[0] | x[0]/(x[0]+const) % result table (post-processing ODE solution): t, x(t), p(t)
}{0}{10}{101}{          % t_0 = 0, t_max = 10, 101 output points
  xinit                 % initial condition x(t=0)
}{
  alpha*x[0]/(x[0]+const) % ODE RHS
}

\begin{document}

\IfFileExists{x_p_vs_t.dat}{}{dummy text\end{document}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis y line*=left, xlabel={$t$},ylabel={\color{blue}$p(t)$}]
    \addplot [no markers, blue] table [x index=0, y index=2] {x_p_vs_t.dat};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[axis x line=none, axis y line*=right, xlabel={$t$}, ylabel={$x(t)$}, ytick distance=1, ymin=0.5, ymax=9.8]
    \addplot [no markers] table [x index=0, y index=1] {x_p_vs_t.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```