# How to plot simply a differential equation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, asymptote

I would like to plot the following differential equation :

[image]

on LaTeX, I have trouble to understand what I need to do for it to work (I know that there have been posts on it but I don't get it). Can someone please tell me which package(s) to use and give me a **simple** example to do so please?

It is to study the speed of a projectile in the gravitational field with air friction. I know all the initial conditions.

Comment: Examples how to solve differential equation with LaTeX can be found e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139141/194703). Whether or not they satisfy your criterion of simplicity, I do not know, but you should not forget that LaTeX is not a computer algebra system.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I am going to try again, I was hoping having something more simple to start with. I know, I just really want to try on LaTeX because my teachers told me it was possible.

Comment: There is also the `pst-ode` package. It is simple to use, perhaps a bit less simple to compile.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, it seemed quite simple to use but it didn't want to compile... So I gave up on that package. Thank you for suggesting it by the way.

Comment: You *can* compile it, just not with `pdflatex` or `xelatex`. You can compile it with `latex`, convert the `dvi` to `pdf`, or use `xelatex`. However, sadly the results of both methods may not be the same.

Comment: My goal was to find something simple where I put my differential equation and initial conditions and that gives me just an input of the solution (a pdf will be just fine) I just don't want to have a png file. For example, I don't want any of the slope fields.

Comment: Ok, thank you I will try to check that.

Comment: Could you please give the values for *k* and *m*m and the initial velocity? Which integration interval do you need (*t*_0, *t*_e)?

Comment: Yes k = 1.15 * 10-3 and m = 58*10^-3

Comment: *v*_0, *t*_0, *t*_e?

Comment: initial time t_0 = 0s, end time t_e = 10, v_0 = 10, thank you AlexG

Comment: If anyone could give me please a script-example with my differential equation or at least first order, with any initial condition, it will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think the question is interesting with a clear description. Here the friction is directly proportional to the square of its instantaneous speed, compare with https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node29.html I have just added tag `tikz-pgf` and `asymptote` to get more attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example uses PSTricks package `pst-ode` to solve the differential equation numerically with the `RKF45` method.

PSTricks requires the `latex`-->`dvips`-->`ps2pdf` workflow for typesetting. Since we use `pgfplots` here, solving the ODE with command `\pstODEsolve` is outsourced into an auxiliary document and the solution is written to file `table.dat`. Therefore, in order to typeset the code listed below, run `pdflatex` or `lualatex` with option `--shell-escape`.

Note that with `RKF45`, precision of the result does not depend on the chosen number of output points. The method uses adaptive step size control. For comparison, the solution with only 4 output points (*t*_0, *t*_1, *t*_2, *t*_e) is plotted against the fine-grained solution with 250 output points.

Typeset with `pdflatex --shell-escape example.tex`.

---

`example.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% solve ODE in auxiliary document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{solve.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-ode}

\begin{document} 
% arguments:
%   algebraicAll --> all arguments in algebraic notation
%   saveData     --> also write result into file `table.dat'
%   `table'      --> PostScript variable that takes result
%   t | x[0]     --> output format in `table' and `table.dat'
%   0, 10        --> integration interval t_0, t_e
%   250          --> number of saved output points t_0, t_1, ..., t_e
%   10           --> initial value
%   9.81 - ...   --> right-hand side of ODE 
\pstODEsolve[algebraicAll,saveData]{table}{ t | y[0] }{ 0 }{ 10 }{ 250 }{ 10 }{ 
  9.81 - 1.15*10^-3 / (58*10^-3) * y[0]^2
}
% for comparison: 4 output points
\pstODEsolve[algebraicAll,saveData]{table2}{ t | y[0] }{ 0 }{ 10 }{ 4 }{ 10 }{ 
  9.81 - 1.15*10^-3 / (58*10^-3) * y[0]^2
}
dummy text
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\immediate\write18{latex solve}
\immediate\write18{dvips solve}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf -dNOSAFER solve.ps}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$t$,
    ylabel=$v$,
    ylabel style={rotate=-90}
  ]
  \addplot [thin,black] table {table2.dat}; % solution with 4 output points
  \addplot [blue] table {table.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, without `--shell-escape`, the auxiliary document `solve.tex` can by typeset manually before typesetting the main document `example.tex`:

```
latex solve
dvips solve
ps2pdf -dNOSAFER solve.ps
pdflatex example
pdflatex example
```

`ps2pdf` must be run with option `-dNOSAFER` in order to allow it to write files (`table.dat`).

Comment: That's great, thank you a lot for taking your time to answer!! I am going to follow your instructions, and will validate your answer afterwards.

Comment: How do you set `--shell-escape` please? I am using MikTeX so I can choose between PdfLaTex or LuaLaTeX as you told me but I am not sure about how to set this option.

Comment: I am running pdflatex on the command line in a terminal. If you run it from within an editor, go to the editor settings, find the command line settings for TeX commands, and add `--shell-escape`. Where to do this is editor-specific. Look into the editor manual. In MiKTeX, you can also open a terminal and run `pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex` on the command line.

Comment: Ok, I have finally suceeded (I think) using `--shell-escape` with the terminal, but it tells me that: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.4 \begin{filecontents}[o
                          verwrite]{solve.tex}`

Comment: That's strange. Did you copy-paste the code above correctly?

Comment: It is indeed. Yes I have copied-pasted all of it and renamed it correctly. Maybe I should save my tex files at a specific place in my computer?

Comment: I am going to try again!

Comment: You could also compile `solve.tex` manually. See bottom of edited answer.

Comment: Well, when I execute what you gave me I have a pdf with the axis but no plot. But most importantly it produces a file with name `[.tex`, is that normal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107441/discussion-between-alexg-and-axel).