# Add regression line to data from file

Tags: pgfplots, external

I would like to display a regression line, as well as a legend for it, reading the raw data from an external file. My code is:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend pos=outer north east]
    \addplot [only marks, mark = *] table {dura_mater.txt};
    \addplot [thick, red] table[
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}
    ] % compute a linear regression from the input table
    {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{$y(x)$}
    \addlegendentry{%
        $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
        \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the input file:

```
X Y
0.0013  0.04
0.0013  0.04
0.0013  -0.01
0.0013  0.00
0.0013  0.05
0.0013  0.04
0.0014  0.01
0.0014  0.00
0.0014  0.04
0.0014  0.03
0.0014  0.07
0.0014  0.07
0.0014  0.07
0.0014  0.05
0.0015  0.04
0.0015  0.03
0.0015  -0.01
0.0015  0.00
0.0015  0.01
0.0015  0.03
0.0015  0.03
0.0015  0.02
0.0015  -0.03
0.0015  0.01
0.0016  0.05
0.0016  0.01
0.0016  -0.02
0.0016  0.02
0.0016  0.00
0.0016  0.01
0.0016  0.02
0.0016  0.06
0.0016  0.07
0.0016  0.09
0.0017  0.01
0.0017  0.01
0.0017  0.02
0.0017  -0.01
0.0017  -0.01
0.0017  0.04
0.0017  0.02
0.0017  -0.02
0.0017  -0.01
0.0017  0.00
0.0018  0.03
0.0018  0.01
0.0018  0.00
0.0018  0.00
0.0018  -0.01
0.0018  0.05
0.0018  0.09
0.0018  0.12
0.0018  0.05
0.0018  0.04
0.0019  0.07
0.0019  0.07
0.0019  0.02
0.0019  0.02
0.0019  0.03
0.0019  0.02
0.0019  0.07
0.0019  0.10
0.0019  0.05
0.0019  0.00
0.0020  0.07
0.0020  0.09
0.0020  0.07
0.0020  0.06
0.0020  0.04
0.0020  0.01
0.0020  0.06
0.0020  0.08
0.0020  0.09
0.0020  0.12
0.0021  0.07
0.0021  0.08
0.0021  0.06
0.0021  0.00
0.0021  0.00
0.0021  0.06
0.0021  0.07
0.0021  0.11
0.0021  0.03
0.0021  -0.01
0.0022  0.02
0.0022  0.02
0.0022  0.12
0.0022  0.13
0.0022  0.12
0.0022  0.17
0.0022  0.16
0.0022  0.09
0.0022  0.09
0.0022  0.10
0.0023  0.05
0.0023  0.13
0.0023  0.07
0.0023  0.10
0.0023  0.13
0.0023  0.17
0.0023  0.15
0.0023  0.09
0.0023  0.05
0.0023  0.03
0.0024  0.03
0.0024  0.11
0.0024  0.12
0.0024  0.12
0.0024  0.17
0.0024  0.16
0.0024  0.15
0.0024  0.16
0.0024  0.07
0.0024  0.08
0.0025  0.11
0.0025  0.09
0.0025  0.07
0.0025  0.09
0.0025  0.11
0.0025  0.07
0.0025  0.01
0.0025  0.01
0.0025  0.08
0.0025  0.13
0.0026  0.08
0.0026  0.12
0.0026  0.16
0.0026  0.13
0.0026  0.07
0.0026  0.07
0.0026  0.14
0.0026  0.13
0.0026  0.12
0.0026  0.12
0.0027  0.14
0.0027  0.14
0.0027  0.11
0.0027  0.08
0.0027  0.09
0.0027  0.19
0.0027  0.20
0.0027  0.12
0.0027  0.13
0.0027  0.16
0.0028  0.18
0.0028  0.14
0.0028  0.11
0.0028  0.12
0.0028  0.12
0.0028  0.12
0.0028  0.18
0.0028  0.15
0.0028  0.12
0.0028  0.07
0.0029  0.11
0.0029  0.13
0.0029  0.17
0.0029  0.11
0.0029  0.11
0.0029  0.14
0.0029  0.21
0.0029  0.21
0.0029  0.20
0.0029  0.20
0.0030  0.18
0.0030  0.16
0.0030  0.17
0.0030  0.15
0.0030  0.17
0.0030  0.17
0.0030  0.16
0.0030  0.15
0.0030  0.12
0.0030  0.15
0.0031  0.15
0.0031  0.11
0.0031  0.06
0.0031  0.09
0.0031  0.21
0.0031  0.20
0.0031  0.20
0.0031  0.22
0.0031  0.21
0.0031  0.19
0.0032  0.18
0.0032  0.14
0.0032  0.08
0.0032  0.09
0.0032  0.12
0.0032  0.18
0.0032  0.22
0.0032  0.21
0.0032  0.22
0.0032  0.21
0.0033  0.20
0.0033  0.17
0.0033  0.18
0.0033  0.22
0.0033  0.22
0.0033  0.15
0.0033  0.12
0.0033  0.13
0.0033  0.15
0.0033  0.18
0.0034  0.19
0.0034  0.19
0.0034  0.16
0.0034  0.17
0.0034  0.13
0.0034  0.21
0.0034  0.20
0.0034  0.12
0.0034  0.19
0.0034  0.21
0.0035  0.19
0.0035  0.17
0.0035  0.15
0.0035  0.19
0.0035  0.21
0.0035  0.26
0.0035  0.27
0.0035  0.26
0.0035  0.22
0.0035  0.24
0.0036  0.21
0.0036  0.23
0.0036  0.25
0.0036  0.29
0.0036  0.27
0.0036  0.25
0.0036  0.22
0.0036  0.21
0.0036  0.24
0.0036  0.27
0.0037  0.20
0.0037  0.24
0.0037  0.20
0.0037  0.20
0.0037  0.22
0.0037  0.21
0.0037  0.26
0.0037  0.24
0.0037  0.23
0.0037  0.21
0.0038  0.20
0.0038  0.24
0.0038  0.28
0.0038  0.28
0.0038  0.23
0.0038  0.24
0.0038  0.24
0.0038  0.26
0.0038  0.30
0.0038  0.25
0.0039  0.26
0.0039  0.19
0.0039  0.17
0.0039  0.22
0.0039  0.22
0.0039  0.25
0.0039  0.28
0.0039  0.34
0.0039  0.32
0.0039  0.41
0.0040  0.44
0.0040  0.41
0.0040  0.37
0.0040  0.33
0.0040  0.25
0.0040  0.16
0.0040  0.22
0.0040  0.31
0.0040  0.34
0.0040  0.35
0.0041  0.30
0.0041  0.31
0.0041  0.31
0.0041  0.34
0.0041  0.37
0.0041  0.33
0.0041  0.29
0.0041  0.28
0.0041  0.33
0.0041  0.28
0.0042  0.27
0.0042  0.28
0.0042  0.30
0.0042  0.30
0.0042  0.30
0.0042  0.36
0.0042  0.31
0.0042  0.30
0.0042  0.29
0.0042  0.26
0.0043  0.33
0.0043  0.33
0.0043  0.33
0.0043  0.35
0.0043  0.34
0.0043  0.36
0.0043  0.33
0.0043  0.33
0.0043  0.34
0.0043  0.35
0.0044  0.35
0.0044  0.34
0.0044  0.35
0.0044  0.38
0.0044  0.40
0.0044  0.40
0.0044  0.37
0.0044  0.31
0.0044  0.35
0.0044  0.41
0.0045  0.41
0.0045  0.40
0.0045  0.41
0.0045  0.41
0.0045  0.36
0.0045  0.36
0.0045  0.39
0.0045  0.39
0.0045  0.34
0.0045  0.37
0.0046  0.37
0.0046  0.45
0.0046  0.45
0.0046  0.38
0.0046  0.35
0.0046  0.42
0.0046  0.41
0.0046  0.38
0.0046  0.39
0.0046  0.42
0.0047  0.40
0.0047  0.40
0.0047  0.34
0.0047  0.38
0.0047  0.43
0.0047  0.47
0.0047  0.55
0.0047  0.52
0.0047  0.45
0.0047  0.37
0.0048  0.36
0.0048  0.35
0.0048  0.46
0.0048  0.45
0.0048  0.47
0.0048  0.48
0.0048  0.43
0.0048  0.45
0.0048  0.45
0.0048  0.50
0.0049  0.54
0.0049  0.60
0.0049  0.59
0.0049  0.50
0.0049  0.43
0.0049  0.39
0.0049  0.45
0.0049  0.54
0.0049  0.54
0.0049  0.49
0.0050  0.49
0.0050  0.48
0.0050  0.49
0.0050  0.51
0.0050  0.56
0.0050  0.57
0.0050  0.54
0.0050  0.51
0.0050  0.59
0.0050  0.63
0.0051  0.55
0.0051  0.53
0.0051  0.54
0.0051  0.52
0.0051  0.51
0.0051  0.56
0.0051  0.58
0.0051  0.53
0.0051  0.51
0.0051  0.53
0.0052  0.58
0.0052  0.66
0.0052  0.66
0.0052  0.61
0.0052  0.58
0.0052  0.55
0.0052  0.61
0.0052  0.67
0.0052  0.62
0.0052  0.57
0.0053  0.56
0.0053  0.56
0.0053  0.59
0.0053  0.69
0.0053  0.71
0.0053  0.72
0.0053  0.69
0.0053  0.69
0.0053  0.64
0.0053  0.61
0.0054  0.58
0.0054  0.61
0.0054  0.63
0.0054  0.61
0.0054  0.63
0.0054  0.60
0.0054  0.63
0.0054  0.65
0.0054  0.67
0.0054  0.71
0.0055  0.73
0.0055  0.70
0.0055  0.71
0.0055  0.67
0.0055  0.65
0.0055  0.73
0.0055  0.78
0.0055  0.71
0.0055  0.68
0.0055  0.72
0.0056  0.69
0.0056  0.73
0.0056  0.85
0.0056  0.84
0.0056  0.79
0.0056  0.73
0.0056  0.69
0.0056  0.67
0.0056  0.71
0.0056  0.78
0.0057  0.82
0.0057  0.80
0.0057  0.80
0.0057  0.83
0.0057  0.85
0.0057  0.83
0.0057  0.77
0.0057  0.82
0.0057  0.83
0.0057  0.80
0.0058  0.79
0.0058  0.78
0.0058  0.75
0.0058  0.83
0.0058  0.82
0.0058  0.78
0.0058  0.80
0.0058  0.85
0.0058  0.82
0.0058  0.82
0.0059  0.91
0.0059  0.95
0.0059  0.91
0.0059  0.88
0.0059  0.89
0.0059  0.89
0.0059  0.88
0.0059  0.89
0.0059  0.89
0.0059  0.90
0.0060  0.93
0.0060  0.87
0.0060  0.89
0.0060  0.92
0.0060  0.93
0.0060  0.89
0.0060  0.90
0.0060  0.95
0.0060  0.97
0.0060  0.97
0.0061  0.96
0.0061  0.91
0.0061  0.90
0.0061  0.97
0.0061  0.95
0.0061  0.97
0.0061  1.02
0.0061  1.02
0.0061  0.98
0.0061  0.99
0.0062  0.98
0.0062  0.98
0.0062  0.99
0.0062  0.98
0.0062  1.02
0.0062  0.98
0.0062  0.97
0.0062  1.04
0.0062  1.04
0.0062  1.05
0.0063  1.03
0.0063  1.03
0.0063  1.04
0.0063  1.02
0.0063  1.03
0.0063  1.00
0.0063  1.07
0.0063  1.11
0.0063  1.06
0.0063  1.09
0.0064  1.15
0.0064  1.12
0.0064  1.12
0.0064  1.09
0.0064  1.03
0.0064  1.02
0.0064  1.12
0.0064  1.19
0.0064  1.16
0.0064  1.15
0.0065  1.14
0.0065  1.12
0.0065  1.10
0.0065  1.16
0.0065  1.23
0.0065  1.21
0.0065  1.20
0.0065  1.20
0.0065  1.28
0.0065  1.22
0.0066  1.21
0.0066  1.19
0.0066  1.16
0.0066  1.16
0.0066  1.21
0.0066  1.26
0.0066  1.23
0.0066  1.14
0.0066  1.16
0.0066  1.19
0.0067  1.20
0.0067  1.21
0.0067  1.27
0.0067  1.30
0.0067  1.26
0.0067  1.22
0.0067  1.22
0.0067  1.25
0.0067  1.28
0.0067  1.26
0.0068  1.20
0.0068  1.24
0.0068  1.30
0.0068  1.35
0.0068  1.32
0.0068  1.28
0.0068  1.25
0.0068  1.31
0.0068  1.42
0.0068  1.38
0.0069  1.40
0.0069  1.38
0.0069  1.32
0.0069  1.30
0.0069  1.34
0.0069  1.33
0.0069  1.40
0.0069  1.42
0.0069  1.33
0.0069  1.39
0.0070  1.40
0.0070  1.39
0.0070  1.46
0.0070  1.45
0.0070  1.38
0.0070  1.42
0.0070  1.47
0.0070  1.45
0.0070  1.47
0.0070  1.48
0.0071  1.40
0.0071  1.41
0.0071  1.43
0.0071  1.46
0.0071  1.48
0.0071  1.51
0.0071  1.49
0.0071  1.51
0.0071  1.46
0.0071  1.48
0.0072  1.48
0.0072  1.48
0.0072  1.49
0.0072  1.52
0.0072  1.48
0.0072  1.57
0.0072  1.61
0.0072  1.51
0.0072  1.47
0.0072  1.46
0.0073  1.52
0.0073  1.55
0.0073  1.58
0.0073  1.52
0.0073  1.55
0.0073  1.62
0.0073  1.60
0.0073  1.61
0.0073  1.60
0.0073  1.60
0.0074  1.64
0.0074  1.63
0.0074  1.63
0.0074  1.60
0.0074  1.64
0.0074  1.61
0.0074  1.64
0.0074  1.61
0.0074  1.63
0.0074  1.64
0.0075  1.63
0.0075  1.69
0.0075  1.71
0.0075  1.72
0.0075  1.78
0.0075  1.74
0.0075  1.73
0.0075  1.73
0.0075  1.70
0.0075  1.76
0.0076  1.76
0.0076  1.77
0.0076  1.77
0.0076  1.78
0.0076  1.74
0.0076  1.76
0.0076  1.78
0.0076  1.84
0.0076  1.85
0.0076  1.88
0.0077  1.86
0.0077  1.84
0.0077  1.82
0.0077  1.75
0.0077  1.76
0.0077  1.81
0.0077  1.81
0.0077  1.83
0.0077  1.82
0.0077  1.84
0.0078  1.89
0.0078  1.90
0.0078  1.86
0.0078  1.80
0.0078  1.83
0.0078  1.85
0.0078  1.84
0.0078  1.84
0.0078  1.81
0.0078  1.84
0.0079  1.91
0.0079  1.89
0.0079  1.89
0.0079  1.92
0.0079  1.91
0.0079  1.89
0.0079  1.87
0.0079  1.90
0.0079  1.94
0.0079  1.94
0.0080  1.97
0.0080  2.00
0.0080  1.94
0.0080  1.96
0.0080  1.98
0.0080  1.96
0.0080  1.95
0.0080  1.95
0.0080  2.02
0.0080  2.03
0.0081  2.05
0.0081  2.05
0.0081  2.02
0.0081  2.05
0.0081  2.02
0.0081  1.97
0.0081  2.02
0.0081  2.05
0.0081  2.05
0.0081  2.01
0.0082  2.00
0.0082  1.98
0.0082  2.04
0.0082  2.03
0.0082  2.06
0.0082  2.05
0.0082  2.11
0.0082  2.15
0.0082  2.18
0.0082  2.16
0.0083  2.05
0.0083  2.10
0.0083  2.12
0.0083  2.12
0.0083  2.14
0.0083  2.16
0.0083  2.20
0.0083  2.15
0.0083  2.10
0.0083  2.17
0.0084  2.18
0.0084  2.24
0.0084  2.25
0.0084  2.21
0.0084  2.22
0.0084  2.21
0.0084  2.17
0.0084  2.19
0.0084  2.22
0.0084  2.23
0.0085  2.28
0.0085  2.26
0.0085  2.24
0.0085  2.23
0.0085  2.23
0.0085  2.25
0.0085  2.30
0.0085  2.32
0.0085  2.25
0.0085  2.26
0.0086  2.30
0.0086  2.23
0.0086  2.23
0.0086  2.24
0.0086  2.26
0.0086  2.28
0.0086  2.27
0.0086  2.31
0.0086  2.33
0.0086  2.30
0.0087  2.28
0.0087  2.30
0.0087  2.32
0.0087  2.34
0.0087  2.37
0.0087  2.38
0.0087  2.37
0.0087  2.36
0.0087  2.38
0.0087  2.32
0.0088  2.39
0.0088  2.43
0.0088  2.37
0.0088  2.38
0.0088  2.37
0.0088  2.39
0.0088  2.42
0.0088  2.41
0.0088  2.45
0.0088  2.46
0.0089  2.40
0.0089  2.46
0.0089  2.42
0.0089  2.44
0.0089  2.43
0.0089  2.54
0.0089  2.45
0.0089  2.42
0.0089  2.49
0.0089  2.49
0.0090  2.46
0.0090  2.49
0.0090  2.50
0.0090  2.51
0.0090  2.51
0.0090  2.50
0.0090  2.55
0.0090  2.60
0.0090  2.62
0.0090  2.64
0.0091  2.59
0.0091  2.55
0.0091  2.57
0.0091  2.60
0.0091  2.57
0.0091  2.66
0.0091  2.66
0.0091  2.58
0.0091  2.54
0.0091  2.57
0.0092  2.55
0.0092  2.64
0.0092  2.69
0.0092  2.60
0.0092  2.58
0.0092  2.63
0.0092  2.66
0.0092  2.68
0.0092  2.69
0.0092  2.72
0.0093  2.72
0.0093  2.65
0.0093  2.66
0.0093  2.72
0.0093  2.72
0.0093  2.70
0.0093  2.71
0.0093  2.68
0.0093  2.66
0.0093  2.66
0.0094  2.72
0.0094  2.75
0.0094  2.71
0.0094  2.71
0.0094  2.72
0.0094  2.74
0.0094  2.71
0.0094  2.74
0.0094  2.73
0.0094  2.77
0.0095  2.80
0.0095  2.74
0.0095  2.78
0.0095  2.80
0.0095  2.81
0.0095  2.83
0.0095  2.81
0.0095  2.73
0.0095  2.76
0.0095  2.85
0.0096  2.93
0.0096  2.91
0.0096  2.95
0.0096  2.96
0.0096  2.93
0.0096  2.92
0.0096  2.91
0.0096  2.91
0.0096  2.94
0.0096  2.96
0.0097  2.99
0.0097  2.94
0.0097  2.96
0.0097  2.97
0.0097  2.95
0.0097  2.97
0.0097  2.96
0.0097  2.90
0.0097  2.94
```

Comment: "Linear regression - trend line with pgfplots – Stefan Pinnow" uses data from inside the code, not from an external file.

Comment: Does that matter? That is, is there any special problem with reading the data from a file when drawing a regression line? A bug or something you need to work around? Reading from an external file is just bog-standard for `pgfplots`, isn't it?

Comment: Did you try to compile the code? Does it work for you? Are you just arguing?

Comment: Not a problem, then it is a duplicate of [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148571/95441) ...

Comment: My problem is that the code works only if I read data from inside, if I use an external file, it doesn't work anymore.